# DynamoDB Composite Key vs Simple Key Performance

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Table: user_group_data

Option 1:

Primary Composite Key:
Partition Key: user_id
Sort Key: group_id

Option 2:
Primary Simple Key:
Partition Key: (user_id + group_id)

Question: Will the lookup speed for a record given both (user_id and group) will be the same for Option 1 and Option 2? (edited)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Looking up something by primary key is an O(1) operation in every DB I've ever heard about.

Given that `user_id` would seem to be unique, it would seem to make more sense to have just
hk: user_id.

Or maybe if you really always have both and you sometimes need all the users in a group, then
hk: group_id
sk: user_id